# Android webview not show full content (Bootstrap and jQuery)

Tags: android, jquery, webview

On my mobil yandex or chrome browser shows full content of this page 
https://www.sbm.org.tr/tr/OnlineIslemler/Sayfalar/TrafikPoliceSorgula.aspx
but my webview not show full content.

Here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

         mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);


        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.sbm.org.tr/tr/OnlineIslemler/Sayfalar/TrafikPoliceSorgula.aspx");

      /*  final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Sayfa", "Yükleniyor....", true);
        progress.show();
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sayfa yüklendi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progress.dismiss(); 
            } `

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bir hata oluştu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });


*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Webview has overview mode. For more information see [setLoadWithOverviewMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLoadWithOverviewMode(boolean))

```
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```